# Spring MVC handle Exceptions and how to show in same view

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

If I handle exceptions with `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler` How can I show error message to user in the same View. For ex. suppose user in "customer/new" view. and invoke "save" action, then it will go to controller and I call methods service layer. but if internal exception occurred in service layer, I want to show error message on same "customer/new" View.

I have written a separate class to handle exceptions as follow.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class DefaultControllerHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({MyProjectException.class, DataAccessException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleInternalErrorException(Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);

        return new ResponseEntity<String>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

    }
}
```

Appreciate your ideas.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you be a little more clearer in what is it exactly that you want. ? Do you want to have a error page or something like that if there is an exception. ?

Comment: In my controller If I call service layer method, (lets say customerService.save(customer); ) and if constrain violation occurred, it fired the above method and error message appeared in browser in plain text. But I want to get this message to the screen that user currently in. In above method can we get reference to current ModelAndView? If can I can add message to model.

Comment: So basically you want the error page to be in the same JSP as the one the user is in.. 
?

Comment: Try this link it may have what you need : http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/

Comment: Thanks for your support. but I don't mean validation errors. I want common place to handle exceptions and add error message to the model in current view.

Comment: It is very good question. I don't know the answer now but I'll do some research to develop solution. It can improve ux and make development easier

Comment: You may try this [how-to-display-exceptions-in-the-same-view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651439/how-to-display-exceptions-in-the-same-view/17037252#17037252)

Answer (score 0):

You can use flash redirect attributes.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/administrator/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String adminAddUser(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
    String redirectUrl = "/administrator/users";
    try {
        userService.save(user);
    } catch (YourServiceException e) {
        redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("errorMessage", "error occured: " + e.getMessage());
        redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("userObject", user);
        redirectUrl = "/administrator/users?form"; // If error - return to same view
    }
    return "redirect:" + redirectUrl;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/administrator/users", params = "form", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html")
public String adminUsersList(@ModelAttribute("errorMessage") final String errorMessage, @ModelAttribute("userObject") final User user Model model) {
    if(user == null) {
            user = new User();
    }
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    if(errorMessage != null) {
        model.addAttribure("errorMessage", errorMessage);
    }
    return "administrator/users/create";
}
```

In that case you must have section on your users.jsp page to show errorMessaage. Something like this:

```
<c:if test="${not empty errorMessage}">${errorMessage}</c:if>
```

If you can fetch url path and redirectAttributes from controller method - you can do this through @ControllerAdvice

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I'm thinking about single place to handle exceptions and add message to whatever the view user currently using. If we can do, we don't need to use try-catch in each controller. We can handle exceptions in a single place using ControllerAdvice and ExceptionHandler, but why we can't add attributes to current ModelAndView?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think about is make your call to the service layer AJAX and then redirect only if there are no errors, if not display the error message.

It might look something like this in your Javascript file

```
$("#someButton").click(function(){
         //make your ajax call
         if (noError){
    window.location.href = contextPath+"/somePath";
         }
        else{
           //display your error message
       }
});
```